# Extract content showed by iFrame, saving it in database

Tags: php, database, variables, iframe

My issue is that I´m looking how to copy or extract a particular content of a website. I get the content from a external feed provider (Iframe format), the content is updated every minute. The Iframe updates new results and for instance, could show from 1 to 2 lines in the table in average at any moment.

Since the information showed by the feed is dynamic, I can´t look for old results. Thus, my goal, (if it´s possible) have a script to read/copy the content within IFrame periodically and it sends it to a MySQL database, within the hosting server. With this would be possible build a results history and be able to show old results.

Comment: Give me a Jsfiddle please! Maybe you are in the famous XY problem. Don't forget to mention me when you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "Iframe format".

If you mean an `<iframe>` Tag, then you can read the data by the given URL in the `<iframe>` Tag.

For example:

```
// Lets assume this is the Iframe
<iframe src="http://google.com/"></iframe> 
// You can see ^ the link where the iframe loads the data from.

// In PHP you could use file_get_contents($link) to return the result string, so...
$url = 'http://google.com/';
$var = filg_get_contents($url);

// $var stores now Googles generated index-file, like a simple GET-Request would do
echo $var;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My next question is that when i try to work with some integer values extracted from that $var....it doesn't work...It doesn't recognize the char as integer and if i try to convert it with intval, with a plus 0, or even with a string comparison (e.g. == "1") it doesn't work. I think mine it's an encoding problem, anyone knows how to resolve it?

Comment: Seems easy to resolve but you should open a new question since it will help people in future when they search for this problem. Also your code (or a minified part where the error happens) that we can reproduce it. Anything else would be guessing at this point.